# Using sed to remove "(double-quotes) on code lines while leaving them on real comments in a vimrc

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sed, awk, vimrc

I'm *finally* learning how to use `sed` to edit configs while installing Ubuntu(Server/Desktop). After much gnashing of teeth and searching about for the proper syntax to *not* remove the `"`(comment double-quotes with exactly *one* blank space afterward(real comments)), as opposed to the lines that have potential code to toggle(*zero* blank spaces or *two* blank spaces for indented lines of code) in the /etc/vim/vimrc file, I figured out how to get things working with the following command:

```
$ sudo sed -i.orig '/^\" [a-zA-Z]\|^"set compatible\|^\" let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1b/! s/^\"//' /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Will the Guru's or apprentices, alike, please let me know if I could have done this better(tighter/cleaner/etc.)?

Example using `awk` for the same result?

Thank you.

Comment: Uncommenting lines or removing lines that are comments?

Comment: Thanks Barry for asking for clarification, I meant just removing the "(double-quote) on lines that contain code while leaving the true comments, commented.

Comment: Np. Keep on truckin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\1` numbered capture variables in the change destination like so `s/^([[:space:]]*)"[[:space:]]*(let .*)/\1\2/`

Also use `sed 'your change;another change' file > file.tmp$$ && mv file.tmp$$ file`

It's the "safer" and portable way to change files in place than `sed -i ...`

For dotfiles like `~/.vimrc` under ~ and conf files under /etc, use git to save them locally. etckeeper is great for /etc management with git.

Some people use `augeas` to edit conf files, or even chef/puppet to manage them automatically.